# Split strings with separator splited into each characters in Scala

Tags: regex, string, scala

I'm trying to split a text bunch with `|` bar separator. `123.123.123.123|000.000.000.000` to each ip address blocks. But each numbers are splited not by `|`.

```
scala> "123.123.123.123|000.000.000.000".split("|")
res30: Array[java.lang.String] = Array("", 1, 2, 3, ., 1, 2, 3, ., 1, 2, 3, ., 1, 2, 3, |, 0, 0, 0, ., 0, 0, 0, ., 0, 0, 0, ., 0, 0, 0)

scala> "123.123.123.123".split("|")
res33: Array[java.lang.String] = Array("", 1, 2, 3, ., 1, 2, 3, ., 1, 2, 3, ., 1, 2, 3)
```

So I put the separator as `Char` and it shows what I intended.

```
scala> "123.123.123.123|000.000.000.000".split('|')
res31: Array[String] = Array(123.123.123.123, 000.000.000.000)

scala> "123.123.123.123".split('|')
res32: Array[String] = Array(123.123.123.123)
```

**Why does single character make a huge difference?**

I've read Scala doc and [StringLike.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.scala#L1), and got no answer.

```
def split(separators: Array[Char]): Array[String]
def split(separator: Char): Array[String]
```

Thanks.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.StringOps), `split` takes a Char as an argument.

Comment: @squiguy not only Char: it can back to [java's split, which takes String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) [regex]

Comment: @om-nom-nom Sure, in that case `|` is special which is obviously what you said in your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Split method accepts either [string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) or character(s). If you use string it will be interpreted as a regexp and "|" is treated as regex 'or' -- in your case it backs to 'every character goes to it's own bin'. Escape it to have raw delimeter:

```
"123.123.123.123|000.000.000.000".split("\\|")
res1: Array[String] = Array(123.123.123.123, 000.000.000.000)
```

Character separator is interpreted as is, so you got the desired result without any fuss

Comment: Thanks @om-nom-nom !
I forgot to remember many of Scala methods are actually from java.lang and java classes. I'll be with javadoc at next time.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, as om-nom-nom correctly mentioned (but didn't provide the example), characters (which are enclosed in single `'`) are also valid:

```
"123.123.123.123|000.000.000.000".split('|')
```

I find this to be more obvious/readable. I'm also assuming that this would be faster, since it does not have to invoke the regex parser. But that is speculation of course, and also unnecessary micro-optimization.

Comment: It should be considerably faster than regexing - no doubt about that. Actually regexing, in that scenario would simply be a mistake. But the question is not about that, and what you suggest is actually already discovered in the question.

Comment: Yes, I said that om-nom-nom had already mentioned it. I just wanted to provide an actual example, since I know many people (including myself) will often only skim an answer for a piece of code, which often is the solution. Since I consider the code example om-nom-nom posted not optimal, I posted my own :)

Comment: @x3ro well, I didn't written this because op did it in his examples (res31) ;-) But I do agree that this is likely to be faster than string version

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Oh, now I feel a little stupid :D I could swear that it wasn't there when I first read the question, but I've probably just overlooked it... My bad

Comment: @x3ro: In other language, I also used to use single quote for all fixed string as the performance concerns you've mentioned above but Scala doesn't seem to be kind for 'string'. What I typed one character with single quotes was a (big) mistake. Thanks to remind me :)